# Как спрятать/показать View?

Tags: java, android

Есть элементы активности, которые не нужны до поры. Хотелось бы их спрятать, а при обработке события показать. Есть ли специальные методы для таких действий?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У класса `View` есть метод [`setVisibility(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)), который принимает одну из трех констант:

1. `View.VISIBLE` – `View` видна;
2. `View.INVISIBLE` – `View` скрыта, но занимает место в `layout`;
3. `View.GONE` – `View` скрыта и не занимает место в `layout`.

Comment: Только что отыскал, но спасибо.